# There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, svg, sass, vuejs3

I am working on Vue 3 application I am using SVG code as a background URL in sass.

```html
$bg-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 14 11'><path fill='#{$color}' d='M4.89557 6.49823L2.79487 4.26513C2.26967 3.70683 1.38251 3.70683 0.857309 4.26513C0.375593 4.77721 0.375593 5.57574 0.857309 6.08781L4.74989 10.2257C5.14476 10.6455 5.81176 10.6455 6.20663 10.2257L13.1427 2.85252C13.6244 2.34044 13.6244 1.54191 13.1427 1.02984C12.6175 0.471537 11.7303 0.471536 11.2051 1.02984L6.06096 6.49823C5.74506 6.83403 5.21146 6.83403 4.89557 6.49823Z'/></svg>");
```

So far everything was working fine but when I updated the vue version + some additional vue related dependencies like vuex, eslint-plugin-vue, and others.

On `npm run serve` project serves correctly but I am started to get a warning below in my code.

```
warning  in data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27 viewBox=%270 0 9 8%27%3e%3cpath fill=%27%23FFFFFF%27 d=%27M4.42111 5.93537C4.22088 6.03839 3.9637 6.0191 3.78597 5.87137L0.177181 2.87153C-0.046034 2.68598 -0.060261 2.36951 0.145404 2.16468C0.351069 1.95985 0.698744 1.94422 0.921959 2.12977L4.14137 4.80594L7.06417 2.15586C7.27904 1.96104 7.62686 1.96165 7.84105 2.15722C8.05524 2.35279 8.05469 2.66927 7.83982 2.86409L4.54449 5.85194C4.50704 5.8859 4.46541 5.91371 4.42111 5.93537Z%27/%3e%3c/svg%3e

There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
```

Comment: Maybe related [to this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5126#issuecomment-312425684)? How do you import Vue etc?

Comment: @kissu thank you, I fixed this the problem was in fill='#{$color}' I was using the sass variable to change the fill of the SVG, and color hex was uppercased just changed color hex from #FFFFFF to #ffffff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the hex color from `#FFFFFF` to `#ffffff` solved the issue apparently.

Comment: Good Evening, I was wondering let's say we have to add a gradient in nuxt for dark mode ---> background: linear-gradient(0.25turn, #5fbe73, #67be60, #72c04f); how we can add this in config please your help will be appreciated from the bottom of my heart.   I tried to like this dark:{"gradient": "linear-gradient(0.25turn, #827f89, #j12uua1, #21hgaa"} but didn't worked

Comment: @ash hi, please open a new question and give as much context as possible so that I could help you efficiently. Detail the kind of config you're expecting, like if you're using Tailwind, any specific package and possibly provide a [repro].

Comment: please sir wait I am doing that 1minute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73895844/17226535 please

Comment: @ash this is not you asking tho.

Comment: yeah one of my friend please as he is new. And i also don't know about that. Please help us