# How to add a Gradient in Nuxt config for dark mode in vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, darkmode

So basically this is the part of my nuxt config.js. I wanted to change into different colors with the switch back and forth. Please help. Basically when I am appending the gradient class its not working as meant to be.

```js
theme: {
  dark: true,
  themes: {
    dark: {
      primary: colors.blue.darken2,
      orange: '#FF000',
      green: '#2DBD09',
      icon_back: '#FF7043',
      gradient: 'linear-gradient(0.25turn, #5fbe73, #67be60, #72c04f)'
      
    },
    light:{
      'container-background': '#e1e1e1',
      green: '#2DD9F',
      icon: '#2DBD9F',
      gradient: 'linear-gradient(0.25turn, #5fbe73, #67be60, #72c04f)'
    },
  },
},
```

index.vue

```html
<v-card-title class="d-flex align-center justify-space-between **gradient**">
  <span class="text-h5">Added Cards</span>
  <AddCard />
</v-card-title>
```

Comment: What is the context of this? Are you using this module? https://color-mode.nuxtjs.org/ Also, what is not working?

Comment: nuxtjs vuetify module

Comment: Please be more specific and provide enough context. [ask]

Comment: basically when using gradient in class

Comment: Did you made a search for that one before posting @ash?

Comment: yeah i did that. Please help

Comment: Does a regular color works well (before trying a gradient)? https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#customizing

Comment: yeah they are working fine

Comment: if I know In this world who can help me is then its only you. Please help. And please upload more youtube videos. World needs that.

Comment: patiently waiting for your response

Comment: I am waiting @kissu please help

Answer (score 3):

Gradients are not useable as Vuetify theme values, as they can only be used in css `background-image`. Vuetify theme colors are used across the framework applying to both `color` and `border-color` properties, which would not be applicable, so is not implemented.

As an alternative to what you are trying to do, you can simply apply your own css class that contains your gradient, and change it conditionally by referencing `this.$vuetify.theme.isDark`

Comment: `this.$vuetify.theme.isDark` is also a solution but it will require some work to be done everywhere it's needed (to apply the conditional), while a CSS file can cascade globally.

Comment: Correct, it's also possible to do with sass variables, but given the lack of detail about the environment, the basic implementation would simply be using `isDark` and a conditional class/style.

As you commented above, it is not something that can be done the way the OP because it is not implemented in Vuetify due to the limitations off css gradients (hence the comment you mentioned from the GH issue)

Comment: Thanks for confirming tho, you probably have more experience than me regarding Vuetify + it's always nice to have a second person agreeing.

Comment: Oh, you're even a core contributor haha: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/graphs/contributors

Comment: yeah, don't really use SO often (mostly live in discord) and saw the post on GH issue.

Comment: thank you very much for helping me love you so much. I hope both you and @kissu will have a great journey towards your destination. It's was super hard for me to conclude as i am not working with these frameworks from a long time.

Comment: how can I apply condition CSS/scss please can you provide me any relative link

Comment: Something like this will work `:class="$vuetify.theme.isDark ? 'dark-gradient' : 'light-gradient'"`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [that answer](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/12166#issuecomment-686339508), I don't think that such feature is supported by Vuetify (and will probably never be).

I would probably do that manually with CSS + some media query (regarding `dark`): https://css-tricks.com/dark-modes-with-css/

It's not like there is a lot of work anyway, you're gonna spend more time trying to achieve that with Vuetify.

Comment: asap surprised with your answer. Beautiful

Comment: @roth you just deleted your question.

Comment: thankyou very much @kissu your kindness will be remembered by me forever and I will also keep this flow with other mates also

Comment: only 1 more please https://stackoverflow.com/q/73898887/17226535 and the best part is that it is from your favorite framework nuxt. please

Comment: please @kissu help please because of this we can't scroll to load more please https://stackoverflow.com/q/73898887/17226535

Comment: It's not working it is just fixing the color. It is not able to detect dark/white. Is that I have to add any package.