# Set Vuetify Slider to a background linear gradient

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

Hi there i am currently trying to modele the same appearance of the RGB Slider under the Colorpicker from Vuetify with the Slider...
Sadly i can not pass a gradient to the color

[image: Colorpicker Slider]

Comment: Looks quite similar to that one no? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73895844/8816585

Comment: I am not creating a theme i just want to style the slider. There needs to be a way since Vuetify implemented theirselves the slider to like that... So i am rly curious how they did it. I looked it up on their github repo but i did not get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to produce a gradient slider with Vuetify, the trick is to target the components css. I use a custom class to insure I only effect desired instances.

### Example:

**HTML**

```html
<v-slider class="CustomSlider"></v-slider>
```

**CSS**

```css
.CustomSlider .v-slider__track-container {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgb(13, 8, 135),
    rgb(225, 100, 98),
    rgb(240, 249, 33)
  ) !important;
  height: 30px;
}

.v-application .CustomSlider .v-slider__track-fill.black {
  opacity: 0;
}

.v-application .CustomSlider .v-slider__track-fill.primary {
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 250) !important;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 250) !important;
}

.v-application .CustomSlider .v-slider__track-background.primary.lighten-3 {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Here is a Example: [Code Pen Example](https://codepen.io/nicoazel/pen/vYVQJYe)

Comment: Thank you very much that works like a charm!